# Can't echo array items

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have an array which I can't seem to access properly, been trying to echo the address. It's called `$user` and here is the print_r for it:

```
Array(    
    [0] => stdClass Object        
    (            
        [id] => 1            
        [firstname] => Casper            
        [lastname] => *lastname*            
        [email] => someEmail            
        [username] => aUsername            
        [password] => *encrypted password*            
        [address] => myAddress            
        [address2] =>             
        [city] =>             
        [state] =>             
        [zipcode] => 1111            
        [join_date] => current timestamp        
    )
)
1
```

It's in codeigniter and so far I've tried:

`echo $user['address'];`

`echo $user->address;`

Both of them with no luck. Any help is greatly appriciated

Comment: Just try with this: `$user[0]->address`

You have a multi-dimensional array and the first index is 0, also inside the first index you have the object.

Comment: wrote `echo $user[0]->address;` and check once

Comment: I also tried `$user[0]['address']` but this one works, thank you Frayne!

Comment: Did you try what i suggest???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a multi-dimensional array and the first index is 0, also inside the first index you have the object. to access an array of object you need to use `->`

You have to echo like given code:

`echo $user[0]->address;`